# Среднее квадратичное массива js

Tags: javascript

например есть такой массив [654,132,45,12,1]

как вычислить среднее квадратичное этого массива?

Answer (score 1):

Так наверное.

```js
let array = [654,132,45,12,1];

let result = Math.sqrt(array.map(item=>item*item).reduce(
(acc, item) => {acc+=item; return acc;})/array.length*1.0);

console.log(result);
```